# SQL express 08 R2 running on Windows datacenter server 08 optimization

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, amazon-ec2, optimization, sql-server-2008

I am running SQL server express R2 on Win Server Data Center 08 (basically Ec2 micro instance). My total allowed memory is 613 MB. When I launched the instance for the first time my total consumed memory in task manager (performance) was hovering around 350 MB to 400 MB. That just leaves 200 MB for SQL server which don't seem sufficient.

I only want to keep services that are directly or indirectly linked to keep sql server running and nothing else. I was wondering what services that are running in the background that are ok to turn off? I want to strip it down to bare minimum.

I know this is bad but I think it's a good point to start as I don't know how many people will be using the web app.

---

TomTom relax, I simply picked the AMI that came with win server 08 and mssql express 08 so I don't have to waste time installing for now unfortunately it was data center edition. I understand your frustration and the discomfort that I've brought upon you. I shall be careful and remember you before I post here again. I don't want to hurt you <3. But nonetheless thanks for replying to this thread.

mrdenny, that is what I figured as well and I too was surprised that I had 200 megs free. And I agree with you that SQL server isn't good choice to run on micro instance. I should be looking for small instance which comes with 1.7 gig of memory and it should be perfect as SQL server express. SQL can consume 1 gig max and .7 can be used for jobs to backup etc but I don't have the $$$$ dineros.

I will run some test soon and post my results here. Will try to run concurrent inserts upto 50+ bots running insert/update/delete and watch activity/ resource monitor to see how it behaves. Additionaly will do some stress testing and create 50 bots that hit the server with select statements.

Will DML and select at the same time. If server does not choke during this small test then I think it's fair enough for the time being (starting out). I don't expect huge traffic anyway.

Thanks all.

Comment: Talk about wasting licenses. Putting a data center edition on a micro instance is about the worst paid i have seen for ages.

Comment: It's an EC2 instance, that's how they come.  Rude comments won't really get you anywhere.

Comment: Putting crappy virtual hardware under a datacenter DOES not get you anywhere, you know - this is why you are here "asking" for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the services that Microsoft sets to start automatically are required to run Windows.  There probably isn't much that you can disable.  The EC2 Micro instances aren't very good for running SQL Server as Windows 2008 takes the better part of a Gig to run by itself.  Honestly I'm amazed that you have 200 Megs left for SQL Server.

Comment: +1. Dont be extreme cheap - at least give if the memory it needs. Memory for database servers normally is measured in gigabytes, not kilobytes.

Comment: These days memory can be measured in TeraBytes on some systems.  To give you some perspective I've got servers with more RAID controller cache than that server has RAM.